# How do I change the colour of an imported button that seems to have default colours?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Imported a button from ICDS which seems to have a few defaults ie Primary buttons, Secondary buttons, Tertiary buttons, Icon buttons, Destructive buttons.

However I want to change it something different using using a purple - color="#5a3eab"

Currently the default colours seem to override any CSS changes I make. As you can see (from commented code) I have tried using color and background. Also tried making the changes in the actual button and css file.

Cant seem to find a solution to override the default theme to whatever colour I want to use.

[ICDS Button component](https://design.sis.gov.uk/components/button)

CSS:

```
.button-with-margin {
  margin: 10px 0px 0px 5px;
  float: right;
  /* background: "#5a3eab"; */
  color: "#5a3eab";
}
```

.tsx:

```
import "./service.css";
import {
  IcButton,
  IcSectionContainer,
  IcSelect,
  IcTypography,
  SlottedSVG,
} from "@ukic/react";

</div>
        <IcButton
          loading={executingService}
          onClick={async () => await handleExecuteClick()}
          className="button-with-margin"
          variant="tertiary"
          // color="#5a3eab"
        >
          <SlottedSVG
            slot="left-icon"
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
            height="24px"
            viewBox="0 0 24 24"
          >
            <path d={mdiArrowRight} />
            <title>Copy Results</title>
          </SlottedSVG>
          Execute
        </IcButton>
      </div>
```

Comment: See [MDN docs - CSS Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity). Use your browser developer tools to see what the selector for the button is. If your CSS selector is more specific or if it has the same specificity and is in a file loaded later, your CSS will override. Otherwise the original selector "wins".

Answer (score 0):

*If you want to change the background color of the button, you'll need to use the background-color property instead of background and you should remove the quotes around the color value.*

```
.button-with-margin {
  margin: 10px 0px 0px 5px;
  float: right;
  background-color: #5a3eab;
  color: #ffffff; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're just setting the color as string and it's not working. You can check it out if you right click and inspect the button on your browser:

[image]

Try set the color as color: #5a3eab; instead of color: "#5a3eab";

In addition, color is not a valid prop for the component IcButton. As you can see, I sent that property color="red" and it's doing nothing.

I think the confusion about double quotes comes here: when you sent anything to a React component prop it goes with double quotes "", if color was a valid prop for IcButton it would go as <IcButton color="#5a3eab" but in css it goes without "" and with : instead of = (color: #5a3eab;)